# how to map dynamic objects to CSV using CSV helper

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I've a list of dynamic objects that I am trying to convert to a CSV but the object data isn't aligning with the column headers correctly.

```
List<dynamic> list = new List<dynamic>();

dynamic dynamicObject = new ExpandoObject();

dynamicObject.Name = "Bob";
dynamicObject.Aug22 = "3 hours";
dynamicObject.Sept22 = "5 hours";

list.Add(dynamicObject);

dynamic dynamicObject2 = new ExpandoObject();

dynamicObject2.Name = "Jane";
dynamicObject2.Aug22 = "7 hours";

list.Add(dynamicObject2);

dynamic dynamicObject3 = new ExpandoObject();

dynamicObject3.Name = "Alex";
dynamicObject3.July22 = "7 hours";
dynamicObject3.Aug22 = "6 hours";
dynamicObject3.Sept22 = "16 hours";

list.Add(dynamicObject3);

using (var csv = new CsvHelper.CsvWriter(Console.Out, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    csv.WriteRecords(list);
}
```

gets me the following output

```
Name,Aug22,Sept22
Bob,3 hours,5 hours
Jane,7 hours
Alex,7 hours,6 hours,16 hours
```

How would I get it to produce something closer to

```
Name,July22,Aug22,Sept22
Bob,,3 hours,5 hours
Jane,,7 hours,
Alex,7 hours,6 hours,16 hours
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# CsvHelper - Records with different number of properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73403526/c-sharp-csvhelper-records-with-different-number-of-properties)

Comment: Yes it does thanks. I'd considered something similar but this is the solution. In the end I changed the requirements and created a flat object
Date, Name, Hours
Aug-22, Bob, 3
Sep-22, Bob, 5

The data is more useable in excel and pivot tables that way too